# How to deal or debug this Redshift error code 15004?

Tags: sql, airflow, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, aqua

In an infrequent way, Redshift throws this error executing from an Airflow DAG a regular query like:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name
            WHERE date_field = '2022-06-02'
            AND category_field ilike '%category_name%';

DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Redshift format: AQUA Scan Error: File not found
  code:      15004
  context:   Block not found.
  query:     91201921
  location:  dory_util.cpp:1226
  process:   worker_thread [pid=88882]
```

I dont find anything related on internet nor the aws redshift docs.

I'm using the PythonOperator, with the postgres hook.
Update edit to answer to Pankaj

Comment: Which operator/sensor you are using? This will help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm using the PythonOperator, with the postgres hook. Update edit to answer to Pankaj
Thanks for pointing it out, I added that to the question